# Is there a way to generate the dtypes as a dictionary in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

When typing `df.dtypes`, we have the list of types.
However, is there a simple way to get the output as

```
{'col1': np.float32, ...}
```

or do I need to code a function myself?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The type returning object of `df.dtypes` is pandas.Series. It has a `to_dict` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 
                   'B': [1., 2.], 
                   'C': ['a', 'b'], 
                   'D': [True, False]})

df
Out: 
   A    B  C      D
0  1  1.0  a   True
1  2  2.0  b  False

df.dtypes
Out: 
A      int64
B    float64
C     object
D       bool
dtype: object

df.dtypes.to_dict()
Out: 
{'A': dtype('int64'),
 'B': dtype('float64'),
 'C': dtype('O'),
 'D': dtype('bool')}
```

The values in the dictionary are from dtype class. If you want the names as strings, you can use apply:

```
df.dtypes.apply(lambda x: x.name).to_dict()
Out: {'A': 'int64', 'B': 'float64', 'C': 'object', 'D': 'bool'}
```

Comment: Sounds good, The only small item is the to_dict() removes the order of the columns ( initial ---> alpha)

Comment: Want to match the dict with the column names for easier visual identification.

Comment: @ayhan Nice Job.   I just want to make a sugestion.  Maybe, if your answer begins with ```df.dtypes.apply(lambda x: x.name).to_dict()``` ...  I think is more  straight foward.... It is just a feedback.  Thanks for you nice answer.