# Save and export dtypes information of a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas DataFrame named df. With `df.dtypes` I can print on screen:

```
arrival_time      object
departure_time    object
drop_off_type      int64
extra             object
pickup_type        int64
stop_headsign     object
stop_id           object
stop_sequence      int64
trip_id           object
dtype: object
```

I want to ***save*** this information so that I can compare it with other data, type-cast things elsewhere, etc. I want to save it into to a local file, recover it elsewhere in another program where the data can't go. But I'm not able to figure out how. Showing the results of various conversions.

```
df.dtypes.to_dict()
{'arrival_time': dtype('O'),
 'departure_time': dtype('O'),
 'drop_off_type': dtype('int64'),
 'extra': dtype('O'),
 'pickup_type': dtype('int64'),
 'stop_headsign': dtype('O'),
 'stop_id': dtype('O'),
 'stop_sequence': dtype('int64'),
 'trip_id': dtype('O')}
----
df.dtypes.to_json()
'{"arrival_time":{"alignment":4,"byteorder":"|","descr":[["","|O"]],"flags":63,"isalignedstruct":false,"isnative":true,"kind":"O","name":"object","ndim":0,"num":17,"str":"|O"},"departure_time":{"alignment":4,"byteorder":"|","descr":[["","|O"]],"flags":63,"isalignedstruct":false,"isnative":true,"kind":"O","name":"object","ndim":0,"num":17,"str":"|O"},"drop_off_type":{"alignment":4,"byteorder":"=","descr":[["","<i8"]],"flags":0,"isalignedstruct":false,"isnative":true,"kind":"i","name":"int64","ndim":0,"num":9,"str":"<i8"},"extra":{"alignment":4,"byteorder":"|","descr":[["","|O"]],"flags":63,"isalignedstruct":false,"isnative":true,"kind":"O","name":"object","ndim":0,"num":17,"str":"|O"},"pickup_type":{"alignment":4,"byteorder":"=","descr":[["","<i8"]],"flags":0,"isalignedstruct":false,"isnative":true,"kind":"i","name":"int64","ndim":0,"num":9,"str":"<i8"},"stop_headsign":{"alignment":4,"byteorder":"|","descr":[["","|O"]],"flags":63,"isalignedstruct":false,"isnative":true,"kind":"O","name":"object","ndim":0,"num":17,"str":"|O"},"stop_id":{"alignment":4,"byteorder":"|","descr":[["","|O"]],"flags":63,"isalignedstruct":false,"isnative":true,"kind":"O","name":"object","ndim":0,"num":17,"str":"|O"},"stop_sequence":{"alignment":4,"byteorder":"=","descr":[["","<i8"]],"flags":0,"isalignedstruct":false,"isnative":true,"kind":"i","name":"int64","ndim":0,"num":9,"str":"<i8"},"trip_id":{"alignment":4,"byteorder":"|","descr":[["","|O"]],"flags":63,"isalignedstruct":false,"isnative":true,"kind":"O","name":"object","ndim":0,"num":17,"str":"|O"}}'
----
json.dumps( df.dtypes.to_dict() )
...
TypeError: dtype('O') is not JSON serializable

----
list(xdf.dtypes)
[dtype('O'),
 dtype('O'),
 dtype('int64'),
 dtype('O'),
 dtype('int64'),
 dtype('O'),
 dtype('O'),
 dtype('int64'),
 dtype('O')]
```

How to save and export/archive dtype information of a pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) returns a [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) object. This means you can manipulate it as you would any regular series in Pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [''], 'B': [1.0], 'C': [1], 'D': [True]})

res = df.dtypes.to_frame('dtypes').reset_index()

print(res)

  index   dtypes
0     A   object
1     B  float64
2     C    int64
3     D     bool
```

**Output to csv / excel / pickle**

You can then use any method you normally would to store a dataframe, such as [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), [`to_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html), etc. Note for distribution pickle is *not* recommended as it is version dependent.

**Output to json**

If you wish to easily store and load as a dictionary, a popular format is `json`. As you found, you need to convert to `str` type first:

```
import json

# first create dictionary
d = res.set_index('index')['dtypes'].astype(str).to_dict()

with open('types.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f)

with open('types.json', 'r') as f:
    data_types = json.load(f)

print(data_types)

{'A': 'object', 'B': 'float64', 'C': 'int64', 'D': 'bool'}
```

Comment: Thanks! `df.dtypes.to_frame('dtypes').reset_index()` was what I was looking for : a way to make that "intangible" info "tangible"! And json is precisely how I intend to store it. Also, thanks for showing a way which doesn't involve the actual data.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I would think there would be a more convenient way to do this as this seems like a common use case.

Comment: For converting the dtypes series to json I think this is clearer `df.dtypes.apply(lambda x: x.name).to_dict()` as seen in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087887/is-there-a-way-to-generate-the-dtypes-as-a-dictionary-in-pandas

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pickle` format.

```
# save
df.to_pickle(file_name)

# load
df = pandas.read_pickle(file_name)
```

Here's the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've found myself putting the dtype information at the head of my CSV files. It's trivial to read it out before the dataframe, which makes it rather nice.

Sample dataframe (shamelessly copied from [@jpp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50423394/2988730)):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [''], 'B': [1.0], 'C': [1], 'D': [True]})
```

To save, I do something like this:

```
with open('test.csv', 'wt') as f:
    f.write(',' + ','.join(map(str, r.dtypes)) + '\n')
    r.to_csv(f, line_terminator='\n')
```

I add the extra comma for the index column here, since I want to write the index. You don't have to do that in general.

Reading is now a 4-liner instead of a one-liner, but arguably much more precise.

```
with open('test.csv', 'rt') as f:
    types = next(f).rstrip().split(',')[1:]
    columns = next(f).rstrip().split(',')[1:]
    test = pd.read_csv(f, dtype=dict(zip(columns, types)), index_col=0, names=columns)
```

I came across this with catalog searches of astronomical data, where a lot of text fields were missing and got loaded incorrectly as float NaNs. The alternative would be to set `low_memory=False` on `read_csv`, but that would make it much more implicit than explicit.